# SQL SELECT from three tables with requirements

Tags: sql, select, join

I have 3 tables:

**Player**:

- playernumber
- name
- initials
- date_of_birth
- gender

**Fine**:

- paymentnumber
- playernumber
- date
- amount

**Committee_member**:

- playernumber
- start_date
- end_date
- function

So the output I'd like to get would be; name, initials, amount. But I only want to see players with a fine that are also committee members. I tried this:

```
SELECT name, initials, amount
FROM Player
JOIN Fine on Player.playernumber = Fine.playernumber
JOIN Committee_member on Player.playernumber = Comittee_member.playernumber
```

Which gives me all the member that have a fine and are also committee members but it gives me a double output which isn't correct. Does anyone know what I can do so I don't get double outputs?

Thanks to the people on this site I found out that `WHERE EXISTS (...)` could solve my problem:

```
SELECT name, initials, amount
FROM Player
JOIN Fine on Player.playernumber = Fine.playernumber
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
FROM Committee_member 
WHERE Player.playernumber = Comittee_member.playernumber)
```

An additional thing you could do is count the amount of fines each committee member has by:

```
SELECT name, initials, COUNT(amount) as 'amount'
FROM Player
JOIN Fine on Player.playernumber = Fine.playernumber
WHERE Player.playernumber IN (SELECT playernumber from Committee_member)
GROUP BY name, initials
```

Comment: Well - it might very well be correct if your data says it. We cannot see your data, so it's hard to say. But it seems you have no need to join into Committee_member. You don't use the data for anything?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen I'd only like to see committee members that have a fine so that's why I need it.

Comment: Instead of joining Comittee_member you could use `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Comittee_member c where c.playernumber = p.playernumber)`

Comment: Yes, then use exists.

Comment: DISTINCT may also help but if you give us a http://sqlfiddle.com/ example. We may help faster

Comment: @maraca thank you :) that did the trick

Comment: @DamienBrils you're welcome, I added another (shorter) solution, it should work also.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that players can be on more than one committee or have more than one fine.  So, use `group by`:

```
SELECT p.name, p.initials, SUM(f.amount) as total_fines
FROM Player JOIN Fine 
     ON p.playernumber = f.playernumber JOIN
     Committee_member cm
     ON p.playernumber = cm.playernumber
GROUP BY p.name, p.initials;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another shorter alternative:

```
SELECT name, initials, amount
FROM Player
JOIN Fine on Player.playernumber = Fine.playernumber
WHERE Player.playernumber IN (SELECT playernumber FROM Committee_member)
```

Comment: Why the downvote? He added both solutions *after* I commented / answered to his question. Btw. he never said he wants to sum the amounts.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a GROUP BY statement to get unique results. See [the MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).